# How do I know if a multi-kanji word like the one in this sentence is a name 美鶴木夜石は怖がらない?

Tags: readings, names

> 美鶴木{みつるぎ}夜石{よいし}は怖がらない

How do I know if a multi-kanji word like the one in this sentence is a name? How does one read it if the furigana was not given and there are multiple pronunciations for the same kanjis?

Comment: Do you mean [this book](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%8E%E3%83%A1%E3%83%8E-%E7%BE%8E%E9%B6%B4%E6%9C%A8%E5%A4%9C%E7%9F%B3%E3%81%AF%E6%80%96%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E6%98%9F%E6%B5%B7%E7%A4%BEFICTIONS-%E4%B8%80-%E8%82%87/dp/4061388290) by your title? It's **鶴**, not 観.

Answer (score 6):

I think it basically comes down to context.

Literate native speakers can usually read most or all of the words on a page, and because they recognize most of the words, when they come to something unknown, they can generally figure out from context what the function of that unknown thing is in a sentence.  For example, if it seems to be the subject of a verb that generally takes human subjects, then it's probably a name.

An unknown string of kanji isn't always a name.  For example, you might run into a technical term like 相貌失認 that you haven't seen before.  But odds are, even if you can't figure out the meaning from the kanji, the rest of the sentence or surrounding context wouldn't make it seem like a name.  (And if the context isn't enough for you to figure out the meaning, you can always look it up!)

Context is probably enough most of the time.  But . . .

Besides context, you can also look at the kanji and see if it *looks* like a word or a name.  If you look at the kanji 美鶴木, you probably won't be able to figure out any sort of meaning by looking at the characters.  (Some kind of beautiful crane tree?)  It doesn't really look like a word.  But if you try sounding it out, you might be able to figure out みつるぎ, [and you might recognize that as a Japanese name](http://blog-imgs-80.fc2.com/e/b/i/ebichintabearuki/mitsurugi.jpg)―even if it isn't usually written with those particular kanji.

If you don't know enough words or can't understand enough to figure it out, or if you can't tell what words or names look like, don't worry!  It'll get easier as you learn more Japanese, and you can always look things up if you get stuck :-)

Comment: Would "crane" be better than "stork"?

Comment: @broccoliforest Ack, I thought I fixed that before I hit 'submit' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is the notion that Kanjis one after another typically indicate that it is a name?

I think you can say that.

> How does one read it if the furigana was not given when there are multiple pronunciation of the said kanjis?

We can't. But typical name Kanjis has typical pronunciation, so we can guess. The book give furigana because the name is not typical, and thus by only Kanji reader cannot tell its reading.